# Why I get ERROR occurred: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I add a validator like that:

```
validate: (req, res, next) => {
  
    req.sanitizeBody("email").normalizeEmail({
      all_lowercase: true}).trim(); 
      
      req.check("password", "Password cannot be empty").notEmpty(); 
     
     // Collect the results of previous validations.
      console.log(req.getValidationResult());
      
      req.getValidationResult().then((error) => {
        if (!error.isEmpty()) {
          req.skip = true; 
          res.locals.redirect = "/route1";  
          next();
          } else {
            next(); // Call the next middleware function.
            }
          });
        }
```

and in the routes I have the following:

```
route.post("/route2", controller.validate, controller.save, controller.redirectView);
```

the save action allows to save a student in my database (mongodb):

```
save : (req, res, next) => {
   
    if (req.skip) next() ;
    let student = {
      email : req.body.email,
      password :  req.body.password,
      zipCode : req.body.zipCode
    };
    const newStudent = new Student(student);
    newStudent
      .save() // method
      .then((student) => {
 
        res.locals.redirect = "/students";
        res.locals.student = student;
        next();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        next(error);
      });
  }
```

and redirectView to rendrer a view.

```
  redirectView : (req, res, next) => {
      const redirectPath = res.locals.redirect;
     
      if(redirectPath) res.redirect(redirectPath);
      next();
  },
```

The validation works (I think since in case of error, the redirectView is executed and the save action is skipped.) but I see in the terminal:

```
Promise { <pending> }
ERROR occurred: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (myapplicationPath\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
```

....

and I have in another file the following code:

```
exports.pageError = (req, res) => {
  let errorCode = httpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  res.status(errorCode);
  res.render("error");
};
```

I cannot usderstand where is my error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086621/10598820

Comment: the TL;DR of that link is `if(redirectPath) { res.redirect(redirectPath); res.end(); } else { next(); }`

Comment: @Bravo still the same error

Comment: you probably did it wrong

Comment: @Bravo I just added your code in place of the if in the redirectView. What you suggest please?